# Rails Console not running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

just started learning programming from Hartl's tutorial. I updated Ruby to 2.3.1 recently (using Rails 4.2.6) and I'm trying to run the console but I'm getting this error:

```
Carloss-MBP:sample_app carlosgrijalva$ rails console
/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Not entirely sure what that means. I notice that it's bringing up Ruby 2.3.0, did I not update Ruby properly?  Should I just reinstall the gems?

Answer (score 0):

After installing a new version of Ruby, you need to install your gems as well. If you are using bundler then just run:

```
# In your folder with `Gemfile` file.
bundle install
```

Comment: Yeah, the gems have already been installed and seem to be working fine yet I'm still getting the same error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your ruby question you need to change your ruby version on your system using RVM or RBENV.

With RVM:

```
rvm use ruby-2.3.1 --default
```

With RBENV:

```
rbenv global 2.3.1
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Had already done that as well and have no idea what's happening. I did manage to find another answer that involved stopping the spring and running the console again which worked. Not entirely sure if that's the proper way to go on about  this though.

Comment: the old "spring stop". i'm not a huge fan of spring for some reason it doesn't "speed up development" for me.